# Using JS if statement to change div class with button (what am I doing wrong)?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

```js
function navtoggle(elementRef) {
  if (document.getElementById('nav').className = 'closed') {
    document.getElementById('nav').className = 'open'
  } else if (document.getElementById('nav').className = 'open') {
    document.getElementById('nav').className = 'closed'
  };

}
```

```css
.closed {
  display: none;
}
.open {
  display: block;
}
#navget {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px black;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <title>HTML Library</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="nav" class="closed">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html"><h1>HOME</h1></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <button onclick="JavaScript: navtoggle(this);" id="navget">NAV</button>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is the Html:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
        <title>HTML Library</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="nav" class="closed">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html"><h1>HOME</h1></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
 <button onclick="JavaScript: navtoggle(this);" id="navget">NAV</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The JS:

```
function navtoggle(elementRef){
if (document.getElementById('nav').className = 'closed') 
    {document.getElementById('nav').className = 'open'}

else if (document.getElementById('nav').className = 'open')
    {document.getElementById('nav').className = 'closed'};

}
```

And the CSS:

```
.closed {
    display: none;
}

.open {
    display: block;
}

#navget {
    width: 100px; height: 100px;
}
```

I know that it would be easier to just use a checkbox, and I do know how to do that. However, I want it to just be a button so that I can make it look better and such. 
I'm rather new to JS so please do not be too harsh for the dumb question. Thank you.

Comment: wrong comparison operator. You are using = instead == inside if condition. Also you dont need Javascript, just onclick="navtogglet(this)" is required

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate code, it did that when I inserted the snippet.

Comment: Also avoid h1 tag inside a tag, its invalid.

Answer (score 0):

in conditional statement you have use "=" instead of compare "=="

```
 if (document.getElementById('nav').className == 'closed') {
    document.getElementById('nav').className = 'open'
  } else if (document.getElementById('nav').className == 'open') {
    document.getElementById('nav').className = 'closed'
```

Answer (score 0):

you have several problems in your sintax I made you a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/AZiGJB?p=preview)  so you can see all the details, but basically:

```
function navtoggle(elementRef){
  if (document.getElementById('nav').className === 'closed')  {
    document.getElementById('nav').className = 'open'
  }
  else if (document.getElementById('nav').className === 'open'){
    document.getElementById('nav').className = 'closed'
  } //You was using semicolon here and that wasn't parsing well
}
```

I don't know if miss to add the script in the header also but let me know if it worked